# NSNumberFormatter, numberFromString and it's behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I would like to ask if this is the behaviour the `NSNumberFormatter` should have. Let's say i have a `String` that not full on numbers ex: `123809d 328190 jdksla`. Why when i use `numberFromString` i do get `nil` instead of the number?(i do include intValue, or doubleValue at the end btw). Isn't that how `NSNumberFormatter` should work or you must give a number converted to string 100% of times in order to just work?
here is the code for the above :

```
import UIKit

let p = "123809d328190jdksla"
let k = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(p)?.doubleValue



k = nil
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Is this just a general question or do you actually want to create numbers from strings that may have non-numeric characters?

Comment: It's general question and i want to take the numbers from a string even if it has one random nonNumerical character. It seems that's not possible with NSNumberFormatter since it returns nil even if it finds one nonNumeric Char. Perhaps you know a way that could solve this issue?

Comment: What result would you want from the string `123809d 328190 jdksla`? Should it give you the first number before the "d"? (123809) The last valid number? (328190)? The result of stripping out all non-numeric characters and then converting all the digits into a number? (123809328190). If you define rules for what you want you could code something to give that result, but NSNumberFormatter says "something's not right" and gives up and returns nil.

Comment: yes indeed. Anyway thank you for your help i got my problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
// First, here's the string
let mixedString = "123809d328190jdksla"

// For convenience let's define the charaterset of all non-numeric characters.
// We do this by inverting the numeric character set.
let nonDecimalCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet

// Now the meat of the method
let numericStrings = mixedString
    .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(nonDecimalCharacterSet) // 1
    .filter { !($0.isEmpty) }                                     // 2
    .reduce("", combine: +)                                       // 3

// 1 Split the string into an array of strings by non-decimal characters
// 2 remove empty strings
// 3 combine the array of strings into a single string

// Now turn the string into a number
let number = Int(numericString)
```

You can put all this into a playground to see how it works out.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the correct behavior

From the documentation of `numberFromString:`

> Return Value
>   An `NSNumber` object created by parsing string using the receiver’s format. **Returns `nil` if there are no numbers in the passed string.**

PS: What number representation of `jdksla` do you expect?

Comment: why would this '123809d' return nil, since it has numbers, but just a d at the end?

Comment: Because the string is not strictly a number and the parser doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: *no numbers* means at least one character which cannot be represented by a number